# Why does the conjugation of Ēsse (Edere) vary dictionary-wise?

Tags: grammar-choice, conjugation, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

I am using LLPSI to learn latin. I came across the word "**ēst**" meaning "**He/She/It eats**". I looked further to see the whole conjugation table.

I found that there are some differences  between some online conjugators. For example,

In **[Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/edo#Latin)**

> 3rd Person singular Present indicative: **edit/ēst**

In **[Cactus2000](https://latin.cactus2000.de/showverb.en.php?verb=edere&vr=1&form=edi):**

> 3rd Person singular Present indicative: **edit/edēst**

What is the meaning of these differences? Are all such forms correct? What does it mean for a verb to have different conjugation forms?

Comment: Can you add links so people can see what you're looking at? I don't see see it on [Cactus](https://latin.cactus2000.de/showverb.en.php?verb=esse&form=esse), whatever that is, and Wiktionary says "edit, ēst", not "ēs".

Comment: @cmw "Cactus2000" actually [gives](https://latin.cactus2000.de/showverb.en.php?verb=edere&vr=1&form=edo) the form *edēst*, which to the best of my knowledge is completely fictional. Beneath the botched quoting and the matter of the disutility of "Cactus2000" lies an interesting question about the irregular forms of *edo*.

Comment: @cmw, yes ēst, I corrected it, I will also add links.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel, If cactus2000 is not that trustworthy, would you please recommend a source for conjugation training? Is wiktionary accurate in this regard? So far, I was using Cactus2000 to build anki decks for conjugation training.

Comment: It looks like the title of your question has a mistake as well; *edire* is not a valid form of the infinitive "to eat", but *edere* is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Sebastian notes, Cactus2000 gives you nonsense. It looks to be poor programming, or maybe a misunderstanding of the data taken from elsewhere.

Wiktionary is correct, but it also provides a few alternate forms that are not unique to *edo, esse*, but all verbs (the syncopated forms).

I personally cannot recommend computer-generated conjugation tables for the purpose of training -- but you don't really need them anyway. Latin only has 5 conjugations (if we make 3rd and 3rd-io distinct conjugations) and a handful of irregular verbs. To learn all the forms doesn't really take that long, and you would be best served by a grammar that lists them all out, like [Allen and Greenough](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/irregular-verbs-fer%C5%8D-and-ed%C5%8D) do. Allen and Greenough provide the irregular forms for *edo, esse*, rather than all the regular forms.

Doing it this way means you're learning a pattern and the exceptions only, which will cut down on how much you have to memorize.

Comment: Still, if the original poster wants full charts, it has been my experience that the Barron's *501 Verbs* book series is reliably accurate, and I believe there's one for Latin. I would certainly be inclined to trust it more than whatever Cactus2000 is – or any site beginning with 'wik(i),' for that matter

Comment: General skepticism toward Wikis not withstanding, I have found the English Wiktionary's Latin declension and conjugation tables very reliable; I have yet to find a mistake in them. Other than that, it's not a very useful dictionary.

Comment: @cnread, The book you recommend (Barron's 501) is available online. Thanks for the refrence. I will certainly be using  that instead.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Tables are good if good parametres have been specified for templates. Some weeks ago I happened to find a mistake for noun *pār, paris* and [corrected](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=par&diff=prev&oldid=75512882) it. ([Previously](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=par&oldid=75409612) *par, pāris* was generated.)